# new to asm and trying to write a function that approximates pi using the leibniz formula

Tags: assembly

The code keeps on breaking and after hours i still can't get it to work, using asm 84x getting the error msg

```
HelloWorld.asm:45: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
```

```
section .bss
    pi  resq 1

section .data
    nega dq -1
    posi dq 1

section .text
    global _start

_start: 
    mov ecx, 10          ; loop var 
    mov eax, 0           ; pi 
    mov qword [pi], 0 ; defines the size of pi 

neg_loop:
    mov eax, nega 
    mov ebx, ecx
    imul ebx, 2
    add ebx, 1
    xor edx, edx         ; clearing register  
    idiv ebx  
    add eax,  [pi]
    mov  [pi], eax
    loop pos_loop        ; jump to second loop to avoid an even/odd check

pos_loop:
    mov eax, posi 
    mov ebx, ecx
    imul ebx, 2
    add ebx, 1
    xor edx, edx         ; clearing register  
    idiv ebx  
    add eax, [pi]
    mov  [pi], eax
    loop neg_loop        ; jump to first loop to avoid an even/odd check

    ; Output the value stored in pi
    xor ecx, ecx
    xor eax, eax 
    xor edx, edx
    mov eax, [pi]
    mul eax, 4 
    mov ecx , [pi]
     ; mul pi/4 so that it is just pi 
    ; system should write whats in the ecx register
    mov eax, 1   ; sys_write
    mov edi, 1   ; stdout
    mov edx, 8   ; Length of the message
   
    

    ; Exit the program
    mov eax, 60  ; system call number (sys_exit)
    xor edi, edi ; exit code 0
    syscall     ; call kernel
```

Im expecting it to write out whats in the pi memory (after its been *4 ) and tried asking a chat bot for help but it only breaks the code even further

Comment: So, have you looked at line 45? Have you consulted an instruction set reference? Did you realize that `MUL` does not take an immediate? Maybe you meant `IMUL` instead (or better yet, use shifting to multiply by powers of two).